# Inspecting branches with command line Git

Tags: git

I'm on the command line in a Git repo. There's a branch `foo`. I want to see which commit `foo` is pointing at; I want to get the commit ID, the committer name, the datetime and the commit message. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick overview over all (local) branches and the commits they point to you can use

```
git branch -vv
```

For details on a commit use

```
git log -n 1 foo
```

Note that git will record both the committer and the author. If you are really interested on the committer name you can use:

```
git log -n1 foo --pretty=fuller
```

You can also specify exactly what you want to see like that:

```
git log -n 1 foo --pretty=format:'%H%n%cn%n%cd%n%s%n%b'
```

For details see `git help log`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `git log` command: `git log foo -n 1`